# How can I mount a VXFS file system under linux or windows?

Tags: linux, unix, data-recovery

Old unix server crashed and now will not boot up, the drives are still accessible though. I need to move the data from that server to a Red Hat server. I was going to use a boot cd to copy the data to a USB drive but I coulnd't find one that can read VxFS file system. I ended up taking an Acronis image of the disk.

Now I don't know what I should do next, any ideas?

Not sure why the unix system wont boot because it gets a kernel panic during start up. This is an old server that is getting replaced with the red hat server.

Edit:

Forgot to mention that the drives are SCSI drives in a RAID so I can only read the drives on the old UNIX server.

Edit2:
I copied the partition to a USB drive now I just need to mount and read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also FreeVXFS, which might help you. Though I do now know how well supported it is, and how compatible it is with your VXFS filesystem.

It's worth looking into I guess:

http://www.advogato.org/proj/FreeVxFS/

Comment: I think centos support freevxfs, I'm downloading a live cd of it right now to see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

Symantec still maintains a vxfs driver for veritas, but it appears you have to purchase it directly from Symantec.  I couldn't find an open source link for it as I was surfing their website.

Assuming you get ahold of this module, you should be able to loopmount the image on the usb key with commands similar to:

`modprobe vxfs;mount -t vxfs -o loop /path/to/partition.img /your/mount/point`

Comment: I'll look around for the module, maybe I will get lucky.

Answer (score 1):

FreeVxFS has been part of the linux kernel for a long time. Many (most?) linux distro comes with the module included. I suppose you'd just need to mount the volume.

Comment: mount -t freexvfs /dev/sda1 /mnt/unix gives me "unknown filesystem type "freevxfs", I tried this is RHEL 6.2 and Knopix

Comment: do you have the freevxfs module? (try `modprobe freevxfs`)